# Extraneous Contours from SliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

> CASE:3866444

---

The straightforward computation,

```
SliceContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, "CenterPlanes", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    Contours -> {#}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], PlotPoints -> 200] & /@ 
    {1, .1, .03, .02}
```

[image]

produces a second set of contours near the origin for larger values of `Contours` and a set of misplaced `Contours` for `Contours -> {0.02}`.  (Lest the reader suppose that `PlotPoints` is too small, I have reproduced the fist plot with `PlotPoints -> 1000` although very slowly and with barely enough memory on a 16GB PC.)

I have three questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a workaround?

and, on a related issue,

3. Why does `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1` (for instance) with no `Contours` specified produce an empty plot?

**Simpler Plots**

Similar undesirable results can be obtained much more rapidly for `PlotPoints -> 1000` with

```
SliceContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    Contours -> {#}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], PlotPoints -> 1000] & /@ 
    {1, .1, .03, .02}
```

[image]

Incidentally, I find surprising the amount of time and memory required to produce these simple plots.  For instance,

```
LeafCount[First[%]]
(* 13718841 *)
```

Comment: I have the same "bug", after some set of parameters including `MaxRecursion` they seems to not work and the resolution is a complete mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a workaround that induces more thinking.

Let's just observe that specifying [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)for *f* based on the given functional form (it has a min of 0 and a max of 3 given the range of values for *x*, *y*, and *z*) works quite well:

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   Contours -> {#}, 
   PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Full, {0, 3}}
] & /@ {1, .1, .03, .02}
```

[image]

Note, however, that while the smaller contour next to the origin is gone, there is an error in the last graph when the contour value for *f* is the smallest. Let's investigate.

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Contours -> Table[a, {a, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Full, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

As we can see, despite the fact that we are starting from 0 in the increment of 0.1, there is a visible area next to the center, where there are no contours. We can zoom in and try to play with [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html):

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   Contours -> Table[a, {a, 0, 3, 0.05}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}, {0, 3}}, 
   PlotPoints -> #] & /@ {10, 50, 100}
```

[image]

Obviously, the result has nothing to do with the sampling of *f* (number of plot points), but exhibits a clear threshold. In this case, it is 0.025. Anything below this number is not going to be plotted as a contour, anything above -- works.

Here comes the question that I promised in the beginning. Why that number? I have experimented with [`ListSliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceContourPlot3D.html) giving it the data sampled with much smaller step, yet the magic number (it is actually slightly above that value) still holds for this particular function. It seems like a certain threshold below which the rendering engine doesn't want to draw, but I am not sure. Is that a bug? Maybe, but doesn't look like so. [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html), [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)etc. don't matter at all.

Comment: I ran your parameters (except `PlotPoints  -> 1000` for the second set of plots in my question and obtained the equivalent of your results. (+1).  Nice work-around.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Glad it works for you! I wonder though, why there is a minimum value of the contour even for the simplest case x==0. `ContourPlot3D ` doesn't have this limitation.