# Spurious contour in SliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm on 12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 and I occasionally see an extra contour appearing in my plot `SliceContourPlot3D`. Same with Wolfram Cloud, 12.3.0 on Linux.

Minimal example is below. Any suggestion how to get rid of it?

```
SliceContourPlot3D[x (0.75` x - 0.25` y) + (-0.25` x + 0.75` y) y, 
 z == -.2, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, ContourShading -> None,
  Contours -> {1.6, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add the option `PlotRange -> {0, All}`

```
SliceContourPlot3D[x (0.75` x - 0.25` y) + (-0.25` x + 0.75` y) y, 
 z == -2/10, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ContourShading -> None, Contours -> {2.5, 1.6}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `PlotRange -> All` + `BoundaryStyle -> None` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. But why? :)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I suspected the issue had something to do with the automatically computed function range as in the 2D cases `ContourPlot[1/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {.5}]` . In 2D default value for `BoundaryStyle` is `None` ; `ContourPlot[1/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {.5}, 
 ContourShading -> None]` gives a single contour as it should. If we add `BoundaryStyle -> Automatic`  we get what seems like two contours (the spurious one is part of the boundary).  For `SliceContourPlot3D` the default value of `BoundaryStyle` is `Automatic` and that of ...

Comment: `PlotRange` is `{Full, Full, Full, Automatic}`. In 2D, `PlotRange -> All` gets rid of the spurious contour. For `SliceContourPlot3D`, _for some reason_, we need to also set `BoundaryStyle -> None` or set `PlotRange` to  `{0,All}`.

Comment: Similar to this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135629/extraneous-contours-from-slicecontourplot3d